# NX Client running on OS X 10.6.3 => NX Server Ubuntu 10.04: weird keymapping issue

Tags: macos, ubuntu, keyboard-layout, x11-forwarding, nomachine

I have been using Ubuntu 9.10 at work after switching from vista. After being (expectedly) disappointed with performance over VNC (via VPN) when logging in from home, I came across the NOMACHINE suite.

Last week, I upgraded from OS X 10.6.2 => 10.6.3 at home. After that, I also updated my NX Client at home to the latest version, as there were issues with recent changes in the OSX X11 setup that rendered the NX connection useless. At that point, everything worked fine.

Fast forward, I upgraded from 9.10 => 10.04 on my work machine the next day, and after coming home and trying to log-in remotely, I noticed that the "s" and "m" keys, when pressed locally, acted as if the meta key was being pressed on the remote machine. That is, the "s" key opens in the Ubuntu login menu (the power icon), and the "m" key opens the messaging menu.

I found some info on using xmodmap to remap keys, however, I can't even begin to fathom what keys I could remap to solve this issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug reported here with workaround -

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-applet/+bug/568401

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answer above from Adam; here is what I did:

You need the "proposed" indicator-applet 0.3.7 from the Synaptic Package Manager.

1. Add the "pre-release" or "(lucid-proposed)" repository in Synaptic Package Manager.
2. Reload the repositories.
3. Do a search for "indicator-applet" - there should be a new version available (0.3.7).
4. Install it.
5. Log out of the user session (X session).

When you log in again it should be fixed!